# How to make sure that an airflow task using OracleStoredProcedureOperator fails when the procedure doesn't run?

Tags: python, oracle, airflow

I used to run oracle procedures using bashoperator wrapped around sqlplus. I came across OracleStoredProcedureOperator and thought it would give me more readability. I've tested it and this is my code:

```
OracleStoredProcedureOperator(
    task_id=f"{table_id}_oracle_load_end_procedure",
    oracle_conn_id=oracle_conn_id,
    procedure="schema.load_table.load_end",
    parameters=[oracle_procedure_argument],
    do_xcom_push=True)
```

It runs procedures, but the task doesn't fail when there's an error. When I run this procedure with a dummy operator, with sqlplus, i get:

```
SQL> BEGIN schema.load_table.load_end('TEST123'); END;

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "schema.LOAD_TABLE", line 124
ORA-06512: at line 1
(...)
ERROR - Task failed with exception
```

With OracleStoredProcedureOperator, on the other hand, I get:

```
{sql.py:375} INFO - Running statement: BEGIN schema.load_table.load_end(:1); END;, parameters: ['TEST123']
{sql.py:384} INFO - Rows affected: 0
Marking task as success, return code 0 etc
```

When i go to xcom of this task in the UI, there's only return value: [TEST123].

How should I modify my code to make sure the task fails when the procedure fails?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure what you get is actually an exception and not just error info printed from within the procedure that actually completed successfully?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'll check it when I'm back at work. If it happens to be the case, do you think there's some workaround to use this operator? Or should I stick with sqlplus? Thanks